# How to convert Period string to actual Period type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of data such as `'1971q1'`, `'1972q2'`, etc. (year followed by quarter) When I do:

```
print(type(df.Quarterly))
```

the answer is `Series`

What I need is to "cast"/convert this column to a genuine pd.Period type so I can do simple time algebra with it.  Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [pd.PeriodIndex()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#periodindex-and-period-range) method.

Assume you have the following DF:

```
In [517]: x
Out[517]:
  str_col
0  1971q1
1  1971q2
2  1971q3
3  1971q4
4  1972q1
5  1972q2
6  1972q3
7  1972q4

In [518]: x.dtypes
Out[518]:
str_col    object
dtype: object
```

Let's create a new 'period' column:

```
In [519]: x['period'] = pd.PeriodIndex(x.str_col, freq='Q')

In [520]: x
Out[520]:
  str_col period
0  1971q1 1971Q1
1  1971q2 1971Q2
2  1971q3 1971Q3
3  1971q4 1971Q4
4  1972q1 1972Q1
5  1972q2 1972Q2
6  1972q3 1972Q3
7  1972q4 1972Q4

In [521]: x.dtypes
Out[521]:
str_col    object
period     object
dtype: object
```

Now we can do "time algebra", for example let's subtract one quarter from each period:

```
In [525]: x.period - 1
Out[525]:
0   1970Q4
1   1971Q1
2   1971Q2
3   1971Q3
4   1971Q4
5   1972Q1
6   1972Q2
7   1972Q3
Name: period, dtype: object
```

Alternatively you can cast the `str_col` column to regular Pandas/NumPy `datetime`:

```
In [527]: pd.to_datetime(x.str_col, errors='coerce')
Out[527]:
0   1971-01-01
1   1971-04-01
2   1971-07-01
3   1971-10-01
4   1972-01-01
5   1972-04-01
6   1972-07-01
7   1972-10-01
Name: str_col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```