# Converting timeseries into datetime format in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the column of dates called `'Activity_Period'` in this format `'200507'` which means July 2005 and I want to convert it to datetime format of `('Y'-'m')` in python.

I tried to use the `datetime.strp` however it shows that the input has to be a string and not a series.

```
df.Activity_Period=datetime.strptime(df.Activity_Period, '%Y-%m')
```

The following is the error I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-ac32eb324a0b> in <module>
----> 1 df.Activity_Period=datetime.strptime(df.Activity_Period, '%Y-%m')

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

Comment: could you show us the code? (use ``` for formatting code blocks)

Comment: Related: [Fastest way to parse a column to datetime in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50507468/190597), or [How to convert Period string to actual Period type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40445076/190597).

Answer (score 1):

```
 import datetime as dt
 import pandas as pd

 #simple example

 timestamp = '200507'
 result = dt.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y%m')
 print(result)


 #Example using pandas series

 series = pd.Series(['200507', '200508', '200509', '200510'])
 series = pd.to_datetime(series, format='%Y%m')
 print(series)


 #for your DF
 df['Activity_Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Activity_Period'], format='%Y%m')
```