# passing Series to pd.PeriodIndex in Pandas results in TypeError: Incorrect dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert a DataFrame column containing string values such as `2020Q2` to period type. I tried the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40447216/13010940 but got the following error: `TypeError: Incorrect dtype`.

```
import pandas as pd
x=pd.DataFrame({'col':['2019Q1', '2019Q2', '2019Q3', '2019Q4', '2020Q1', '2020Q2']})
x['period']=pd.PeriodIndex(x.col, freq='Q-Oct')
```

I tried `PeriodIndex` for a single string, too.

```
pd.PeriodIndex('2020Q2', freq='Q-Oct')
```

This also gives an error: `ValueError: Given date string not likely a datetime.`

Of course, I can convert  string to datetime first and then covert it to period.

```
x['period']=pd.to_datetime(x.col).dt.to_period(freq='Q-oct')
```

and

```
pd.to_datetime('2020Q2').to_period(freq='Q-oct')
```

But I think there is a nicer solution.

Comment: Here are some nicer way, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53898522/4985099

Comment: @Sushanth That thread is talking about converting periods to dates. FWIW OP is already doing the right things. Unfortunately, they've hit upon a rather niche regression bug. PTAL my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### This is a regression bug that has been fixed for version 1.1. Please see [GH26109](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26109).

Your method *is* correct, this is a regression bug introduced after 0.23 I believe (?) which causes it to not accept periods in a Series. Try converting it as a list or array:

```
pd.__version__
# '1.0.4'

pd.PeriodIndex(x['col'], freq='Q-Oct')
# TypeError: Incorrect dtype

# pd.PeriodIndex(x['col'].to_numpy(), freq='Q-Oct')  # also works
pd.PeriodIndex(x['col'].tolist(), freq='Q-Oct')
# PeriodIndex(['2019Q1', '2019Q2', '2019Q3', '2019Q4', '2020Q1', '2020Q2'], 
#             dtype='period[Q-OCT]', freq='Q-OCT')
```

---

This works on 1.1:

```
pd.__version__
# '1.1.0.dev0+2004.g8d10bfb6f'

pd.PeriodIndex(x['col'], freq='Q-Oct')
# PeriodIndex(['2019Q1', '2019Q2', '2019Q3', '2019Q4', '2020Q1', '2020Q2'], 
#             dtype='period[Q-OCT]', freq='Q-OCT')
```

When the time is right, just upgrade!